# Вопрос про constexpr

Tags: c++

Насколько мне известно, благодаря constexpr, вычисления происходят во время компиляции.
Но почему при отладке кода, в переменной хранится совсем другое значение?

```
#include <iostream>


constexpr int new_sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int main()
{

    constexpr auto i = new_sum(2,2);
    std::cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это ведь вы показываете экран с отладчиком? Посмотрите значение `i` в следующей строке (д.б. уже 4). Просто отладчик, становясь на строку, обычно еще не исполняет код в ней. (например, у меня gdb в этой строке показвает `i = 0` (а на следующей уже 4)). Что касается `constexpr`. Естественно, вычисления проведены во время компиляции, но полученное число 4 будет загружено в память, сответствующую переменной `i`, не во время компиляции, а в то время, когда должны были бы происходить эти вычисления при исполнении кода программы